# Java for-loop, do i need continue statement here?

Tags: java

Consider this code:

```
if (int a == 0) {
    System.out.println("hello");
    continue;
}
```

This `if` is part of a `for` loop in java. What is the significane of continue statement here? I know `continue` is the opposite of `break` so that it wont break out of the loop rather just skip that iteration for anything below it. But in case it is inside an `if` statement, do I really need it like this?

Answer (score 7):

No, you don't *need* to use `continue` there, you can use an `else` block instead:

```
    if (a == 0) {
         System.out.println("hello");
    } else {
         // The rest of the loop body goes here.
    }
```

Which is better is a style issue. Sometimes one is better, sometimes the other - it depends on what the typical flow should be and which flow you want to emphasize in the code.

Comment: +1, in particular for: *"it depends on what the typical flow should be and which flow you want to emphasize in the code"*

Answer (score 1):

If this is the last statement of the `for` loop - no, you don't need it. Otherwise you need it to skip everything below the `if`-clause. If you don't want to skip it, then don't use `continue`.

[Here is an explanation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) with examples of what `continue` is doing.

Answer (score 0):

`continue` means that the statements below the `if` block won't work. If this is the behavior you need, you should `continue`. Otherwise it is not needed.